# Get Client Session by Session Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, session-cookies

We are currently implementing a Punchout solution for our ASP.net ecommerce store. We need to be able to send a url to an external application which will direct the user to an existing Http.Session in our store.

This was easy to do with cookieless sessions. However, cookieless session's are not fully supported in MVC and disables some of our existing functionality.

Is there a way to pass a session ID as a query string to load an existing Http.Session in ASP.net?

Comment: Did you try HttpContext.Session.SessionID?

Comment: @smirnov, I don't think the question was about how to retrieve the session id, but how to "load up" an entire session, knowing the id.

Comment: Do you mean, did I try and assign a session ID to HttpContext.Session.SessionID? If so, Because HttpContext.Session.SessionID is a readonly property.

Comment: @AndreiV, you are correct. I need to get access to a session object stored in the server via session id

Comment: @CalvinPietersen, I like your idea but I don't really think that's possible.

Comment: @AndreiV, What would be the best alternate solution? How is this problem commonly handled? I cant really find much on it, but I've seen plenty of websites that have url links to existing sessions.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the problem? I understand you want to create a new asp.net session programmatically and assign it to a user (e.g. assign a shopping cart). If true, why can't this be done in a "normal" way (asp.net assigns a new session to the user, you add items into this session, etc)?

Comment: @CalvinPietersen, I can't really imagine the entire context. I would try to persist all the session data (along with the session id) and when a new request comes, load up all the data related to the specified session id. You would have to pay attention to session hijacking, so take into account the user name.

Comment: Have you tried to change value of ASP.NET_SessionId cookie on page you redirect to to SessionId you pass in query string?

Answer (score 1):

Its is not possible to load a session base on any parameter, this is done automatically on asp.net.

What you can do is to use a local database, and connect the user data with an id, encode that id somehow, and send it to your remote service, then read it back and load your data.